# Facing issue with the serialisation of a String of List of List

Tags: java, json, objectmapper, jsonparser

I am getting a score from an API which is a list of list.

Response

```
"score":"[[3289780, 0.873], [25046762, 0.3], [18124806, 0.259], [25587374, 0.047], [5725643, 0.045], [23887210, 0.03], [26185297, 0.005]]"
```

But when the scores are not there it's returning empty list for score.

Response in case of empty

```
"score":"\"\""
or
"score":""
```

i am using json parser for parsing and in the 2nd case where score = "", i can even check for empty string an not parse it.
but in the case of "score":"""" i can't make this check.

I want my parser to be generalised

Parse code

```
List<List<Object>> scores = new ArrayList<>();
scores = JsonUtil.deserialize(scoreResponse, scores.getClass());
```

scoreResponse is a string which will have values from score.

JsonUtils deserialize code

```
public static <T> T deserialize(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(json, clazz);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot deserialize given object", ex);
        }
    }
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll try to solve what I can.
In the case of:

```
score= "\"\""
```

It seems that " is used to represent the " (quotes) character in that instance.
So in your check you could say:

```
if (score == "\"\"") {return null;}
```

for example.

Try that out, hope it helps